# Closure of $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Is the closure of $\Bbb R$ equal to $\Bbb R$ itself or the extended real numbers $\bar{\Bbb R}$?

Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on which topology you are talking about.

If it is the topology on the real number system $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{R}$ is the closure of itself.

If it is the topology on the extended real number system $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, then $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is the closure of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

It matters with respected to which sense of convergence you are speaking of.  If a point is in the space because it is the limit of a cauchy sequence, then yes R is it's own closure.